# content visibility and overflow collision

Tags: html, css

I need `content-visibility:auto` because of better page loading performance
but buttons are half outside of parent and are not visible if `content-visibility` is `auto`
any idea ?

```css
.wrap{
width:50%;
height:54px;
position:relative;
background:orange;
content-visibility:auto;
overflow:visible;
}
button{
position:absolute;
right:-20px;
top:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
<button>CLICK</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to note that there is no problem on Safari (tested on IOS 15) or Firefox (tested on Windows 10) but the button is cut off on Chrome/Edge (tested on Windows 10).

Comment: I was wrong - there is a problem on Safari and FF - they haven't implemented it it seems.

Answer (score 1):

content-visibility seems not to be implemented on Firefox or Safari as of today (Decemer 2021).

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content-visibility

So, the result 'looks right' on those browsers as the CSS propeprty setting is just ignored.

On Edge/Chrome it appears that there is an attempt at implementing contentIvisibility but I do not understand why this means the button is cut off outside its parent element.

So this is not a full explanation - hopefully someone can add more information on exactly how this CSS property is to work.